# R | pivot_wider() | How to handle duplicates in "values_from" column

Tags: r, pivot

I have a dataframe:

```
ID     questions    value
A          1          8
A         1.1         7
A         1.2        -3
B          1          7
B         4.3         7
...       ...        ...
```

I'm trying to pivot the data on "questions" such that the data frame will look like this:

```
ID      1        1.1      1.2     4.3
A       8         7        -3      NA
B      ...       ...      ...      7
...
```

Using the pivot_wider() function, I ran into an error:

```
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = question, values_from = value)

Values in `rating` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(rating = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(rating = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(rating = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates
```

So I looked this issue up, and I think the error was because the "value" column has duplicates. A search on stackoverflow showed someone else had the same problem: [pivot_wider issue "Values in `values_from` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837773/pivot-wider-issue-values-in-values-from-are-not-uniquely-identified-output-w).

Their solution was to "Create a unique identifier row for each name and then use pivot_wider". However, this didn't work for me, as if I did this, there were duplicates in ID

```
df %>% group_by(question) %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = question, values_from = value) %>% select(-row)

##########################################
ID        1        1.1      1.2
A         8        NA       -3 
A         NA       7        NA
...       ...      ...      ...
```

Here, A should only appear once in ID and all its values should be in one row, not spread over 2. My actual data set is far larger than this, and for some reason, a handful of ID's will be duplicated (but not all).

Can someone help me? Thanks

Here's a sample of my data in csv format

```
question,ID,value
-10.4,78864__90000,68
-10.8,78864__90000,66
1.1,78864__93500,2
1.2,78864__93500,2
1.3,78864__93500,2
1.4,78864__93500,2
1.5,78864__93500,2
1.6,78864__93500,2
2,78864__93500,8
3.1,78864__93500,90
1.1,78864__93501,2
1.2,78864__93501,1
1.3,78864__93501,1
1.4,78864__93501,0
1.5,78864__93501,0
1.6,78864__93501,1
2,78864__93501,4
3.1,78864__93501,65
1.1,78864__93502,1
1.2,78864__93502,1
1.3,78864__93502,0
1.4,78864__93502,1
1.5,78864__93502,0
1.6,78864__93502,2
2,78864__93502,8
3.1,78864__93502,75
1.1,78864__93503,1
1.2,78864__93503,2
1.3,78864__93503,2
1.4,78864__93503,1
1.5,78864__93503,1
1.6,78864__93503,2
2,78864__93503,8
3.1,78864__93503,70
1.1,78864__93504,1
1.2,78864__93504,0
1.3,78864__93504,2
1.4,78864__93504,0
1.5,78864__93504,0
1.6,78864__93504,2
2,78864__93504,4
3.1,78864__93504,70
1.1,78864__93506,1
1.2,78864__93506,1
1.3,78864__93506,1
1.4,78864__93506,0
1.5,78864__93506,1
1.6,78864__93506,2
2,78864__93506,8
3.1,78864__93506,75
1.1,78864__93508,1
1.2,78864__93508,1
1.3,78864__93508,1
1.4,78864__93508,0
1.5,78864__93508,1
1.6,78864__93508,1
2,78864__93508,8
3.1,78864__93508,65
1.1,78864__93511,1
1.2,78864__93511,1
1.3,78864__93511,1
1.4,78864__93511,0
1.5,78864__93511,0
1.6,78864__93511,1
2,78864__93511,4
3.1,78864__93511,50
1.1,78864__93512,1
1.2,78864__93512,1
1.3,78864__93512,1
1.4,78864__93512,1
1.5,78864__93512,1
1.6,78864__93512,1
2,78864__93512,8
3.1,78864__93512,60
1.1,78864__93515,2
1.2,78864__93515,2
1.3,78864__93515,2
1.4,78864__93515,1
1.5,78864__93515,2
1.6,78864__93515,2
2,78864__93515,16
3.1,78864__93515,60
-10.7,78905__89998,85
-10.4,78905__89999,73
-10.4,78905__90000,74
-10.7,78905__90000,96
1,78905__93515,16
2,78905__93515,16
3.1,78905__93515,90
1,78905__93524,4
2,78905__93524,8
3.1,78905__93524,50
1,78905__93525,8
2,78905__93525,8
3.1,78905__93525,70
1,78905__93526,16
2,78905__93526,8
3.1,78905__93526,90
1,78905__93527,8
2,78905__93527,4
3.1,78905__93527,80
1,78905__93528,8
2,78905__93528,16
3.1,78905__93528,95
1,78905__93529,8
2,78905__93529,8
3.1,78905__93529,85
1,78905__93531,4
2,78905__93531,8
3.1,78905__93531,60
1,78905__93532,8
2,78905__93532,8
3.1,78905__93532,80
1,78905__93533,4
2,78905__93533,8
3.1,78905__93533,50
1,78905__93534,8
2,78905__93534,4
3.1,78905__93534,75
1,78905__93536,16
2,78905__93536,8
3.1,78905__93536,80
-10.6,78911__89995,51
-10.8,78911__89996,57
-10.8,78911__89997,55
-10.7,78911__89998,58
-10.6,78911__89999,97
-10.6,78911__90000,70
-10.8,78911__90000,55
2,78911__93500,8
3.1,78911__93500,90
1.1,78911__93502,2
1.2,78911__93502,2
1.3,78911__93502,2
1.4,78911__93502,2
1.5,78911__93502,2
1.6,78911__93502,2
2,78911__93502,8
3.1,78911__93502,80
1.1,78911__93508,1
1.2,78911__93508,2
1.3,78911__93508,2
1.4,78911__93508,1
1.5,78911__93508,2
1.6,78911__93508,2
2,78911__93508,8
3.1,78911__93508,65
1.1,78911__93509,2
1.2,78911__93509,2
1.3,78911__93509,2
1.4,78911__93509,2
1.5,78911__93509,2
1.6,78911__93509,2
2,78911__93509,16
3.1,78911__93509,50
1,78911__93511,0
1.1,78911__93511,1
1.2,78911__93511,2
1.3,78911__93511,2
1.4,78911__93511,0
1.5,78911__93511,0
1.6,78911__93511,2
2,78911__93511,8
3.1,78911__93511,50
1.1,78911__93512,1
1.2,78911__93512,1
1.3,78911__93512,1
1.4,78911__93512,1
1.5,78911__93512,1
1.6,78911__93512,2
2,78911__93512,8
3.1,78911__93512,50
1.1,78911__93515,2
1.2,78911__93515,2
1.3,78911__93515,2
1.4,78911__93515,2
1.5,78911__93515,1
1.6,78911__93515,2
2,78911__93515,16
3.1,78911__93515,90
1.1,78911__93538,2
1.2,78911__93538,2
1.3,78911__93538,2
1.4,78911__93538,0
1.5,78911__93538,2
1.6,78911__93538,2
2,78911__93538,8
3.1,78911__93538,80
-10.6,78926__89996,80
-10.6,78926__89997,78
-10.7,78926__89998,90
-10.4,78926__89999,55
-10.4,78926__90000,52
-10.6,78926__90000,87
-10.7,78926__90000,92
1,78926__93515,16
2,78926__93515,16
3.1,78926__93515,90
1,78926__93524,16
2,78926__93524,8
3.1,78926__93524,90
1,78926__93525,16
2,78926__93525,8
3.1,78926__93525,75
1,78926__93531,8
2,78926__93531,8
3.1,78926__93531,60
-10.6,78934__89992,67
-10.4,78934__89993,60
-10.4,78934__89994,84
-10.6,78934__89995,80
-10.4,78934__89996,74
-10.6,78934__89997,82
-10.4,78934__89998,66
-10.6,78934__89999,88
-10.4,78934__90000,81
-10.6,78934__90000,82
-10.7,78934__90000,69
1,78934__93502,16
2,78934__93502,8
3.1,78934__93502,80
1,78934__93515,16
2,78934__93515,16
3.1,78934__93515,50
1,78934__93524,16
2,78934__93524,16
3.1,78934__93524,90
1,78934__93526,16
2,78934__93526,16
3.1,78934__93526,95
1,78934__93527,8
2,78934__93527,8
3.1,78934__93527,80
1,78934__93528,16
2,78934__93528,16
3.1,78934__93528,90
1,78934__93529,16
2,78934__93529,8
3.1,78934__93529,85
1,78934__93530,8
2,78934__93530,8
3.1,78934__93530,50
1,78934__93531,16
2,78934__93531,8
3.1,78934__93531,70
1,78934__93532,8
2,78934__93532,8
3.1,78934__93532,80
-10.6,78935__89998,92
-10.4,78935__89999,74
-10.4,78935__90000,56
-10.7,78935__90000,81
1,78935__93515,16
2,78935__93515,16
3.1,78935__93515,95
1,78935__93524,16
2,78935__93524,16
3.1,78935__93524,90
1,78935__93526,16
2,78935__93526,8
3.1,78935__93526,90
1,78935__93527,8
2,78935__93527,4
3.1,78935__93527,70
1,78935__93528,8
2,78935__93528,16
3.1,78935__93528,95
1,78935__93529,16
2,78935__93529,8
3.1,78935__93529,90
1,78935__93530,8
2,78935__93530,8
3.1,78935__93530,65
1,78935__93531,16
2,78935__93531,8
3.1,78935__93531,80
1,78935__93536,16
2,78935__93536,8
3.1,78935__93536,90
-10.6,78936__89997,76
-10.7,78936__89998,85
-10.4,78936__89999,80
-10.4,78936__90000,81
-10.6,78936__90000,73
-10.7,78936__90000,94
1,78936__93515,16
2,78936__93515,16
3.1,78936__93515,95
1,78936__93526,8
2,78936__93526,8
3.1,78936__93526,90
1,78936__93527,8
2,78936__93527,8
3.1,78936__93527,80
1,78936__93528,8
2,78936__93528,8
3.1,78936__93528,90
1,78936__93529,16
2,78936__93529,16
3.1,78936__93529,90
1,78936__93531,16
2,78936__93531,2
3.1,78936__93531,80
1,78936__93532,8
2,78936__93532,8
3.1,78936__93532,80
1,78936__93536,16
2,78936__93536,16
3.1,78936__93536,90
-10.7,78937__89994,90
-10.6,78937__89995,76
-10.4,78937__89996,84
-10.6,78937__89997,74
-10.6,78937__89998,82
-10.5,78937__89999,50
-10.4,78937__90000,74
-10.6,78937__90000,92
-10.7,78937__90000,84
1,78937__93515,16
2,78937__93515,16
3.1,78937__93515,90
1,78937__93524,16
2,78937__93524,8
3.1,78937__93524,95
1,78937__93525,16
2,78937__93525,4
3.1,78937__93525,75
1,78937__93526,4
2,78937__93526,8
3.1,78937__93526,70
1,78937__93527,8
2,78937__93527,8
3.1,78937__93527,80
1,78937__93530,4
2,78937__93530,8
3.1,78937__93530,60
1,78937__93531,16
2,78937__93531,8
3.1,78937__93531,85
1,78937__93536,8
2,78937__93536,8
3.1,78937__93536,90
-10.4,78989__90000,68
-10.6,78989__90000,70
1.1,78989__93501,2
1.2,78989__93501,2
1.3,78989__93501,2
1.4,78989__93501,0
1.5,78989__93501,2
1.6,78989__93501,2
2,78989__93501,8
3.1,78989__93501,80
1,78989__93502,0
1.1,78989__93502,1
1.2,78989__93502,1
1.3,78989__93502,1
1.4,78989__93502,1
1.5,78989__93502,1
1.6,78989__93502,1
2,78989__93502,0
3.1,78989__93502,50
1.1,78989__93503,2
1.2,78989__93503,2
1.3,78989__93503,2
1.4,78989__93503,1
1.5,78989__93503,2
1.6,78989__93503,2
2,78989__93503,8
3.1,78989__93503,65
1.1,78989__93506,1
1.2,78989__93506,2
1.3,78989__93506,1
1.4,78989__93506,1
1.5,78989__93506,1
1.6,78989__93506,2
2,78989__93506,8
3.1,78989__93506,70
1,78989__93507,0
1.1,78989__93507,2
1.2,78989__93507,2
1.3,78989__93507,2
1.4,78989__93507,2
1.5,78989__93507,2
1.6,78989__93507,2
2,78989__93507,16
3.1,78989__93507,50
1.1,78989__93511,2
1.2,78989__93511,2
1.3,78989__93511,0
1.4,78989__93511,0
1.5,78989__93511,2
1.6,78989__93511,2
2,78989__93511,8
3.1,78989__93511,50
1.1,78989__93512,2
1.2,78989__93512,1
1.3,78989__93512,1
1.4,78989__93512,0
1.5,78989__93512,1
1.6,78989__93512,1
2,78989__93512,8
3.1,78989__93512,70
1.1,78989__93515,2
1.2,78989__93515,2
1.3,78989__93515,2
1.4,78989__93515,2
1.5,78989__93515,2
1.6,78989__93515,2
2,78989__93515,16
3.1,78989__93515,90
-10.7,78990__89993,85
-10.6,78990__89994,67
-10.4,78990__89995,89
-10.6,78990__89996,79
-10.4,78990__89997,51
-10.6,78990__89998,74
-10.4,78990__89999,74
-10.4,78990__90000,91
-10.6,78990__90000,80
1.1,78990__93500,2
1.2,78990__93500,2
1.3,78990__93500,2
1.4,78990__93500,2
1.5,78990__93500,2
1.6,78990__93500,2
2,78990__93500,8
3.1,78990__93500,50
1.1,78990__93501,2
1.2,78990__93501,2
1.3,78990__93501,2
1.4,78990__93501,1
1.5,78990__93501,1
1.6,78990__93501,1
2,78990__93501,8
3.1,78990__93501,80
1.1,78990__93502,2
1.2,78990__93502,2
1.3,78990__93502,2
1.4,78990__93502,2
1.5,78990__93502,2
1.6,78990__93502,2
2,78990__93502,16
3.1,78990__93502,80
1.1,78990__93503,1
1.2,78990__93503,1
1.3,78990__93503,2
1.4,78990__93503,1
1.5,78990__93503,2
1.6,78990__93503,2
2,78990__93503,8
3.1,78990__93503,70
1.1,78990__93506,1
1.2,78990__93506,1
1.3,78990__93506,1
1.4,78990__93506,1
1.5,78990__93506,1
1.6,78990__93506,2
2,78990__93506,8
3.1,78990__93506,75
1.1,78990__93507,2
1.2,78990__93507,2
1.3,78990__93507,2
1.4,78990__93507,2
1.5,78990__93507,2
1.6,78990__93507,2
2,78990__93507,16
3.1,78990__93507,90
1.1,78990__93508,2
1.2,78990__93508,2
1.3,78990__93508,2
1.4,78990__93508,2
1.5,78990__93508,1
1.6,78990__93508,2
2,78990__93508,8
3.1,78990__93508,75
1.1,78990__93509,2
1.2,78990__93509,2
1.3,78990__93509,2
1.4,78990__93509,2
1.5,78990__93509,2
1.6,78990__93509,2
2,78990__93509,16
3.1,78990__93509,85
1,78990__93511,0
1.1,78990__93511,2
1.2,78990__93511,2
1.3,78990__93511,2
1.4,78990__93511,0
1.5,78990__93511,1
1.6,78990__93511,2
2,78990__93511,8
3.1,78990__93511,50
1.1,78990__93512,2
1.2,78990__93512,2
1.3,78990__93512,2
1.4,78990__93512,1
1.5,78990__93512,2
1.6,78990__93512,2
2,78990__93512,8
3.1,78990__93512,80
1.1,78990__93515,2
1.2,78990__93515,2
1.3,78990__93515,2
1.4,78990__93515,2
1.5,78990__93515,2
1.6,78990__93515,2
2,78990__93515,16
3.1,78990__93515,90
-10.4,79022__89998,84
-10.4,79022__89999,52
-10.4,79022__90000,88
2,79022__93500,8
3.1,79022__93500,100
2,79022__93503,16
3.1,79022__93503,85
2,79022__93507,16
3.1,79022__93507,90
2,79022__93509,16
3.1,79022__93509,90
2,79022__93515,16
3.1,79022__93515,100
2,79083__93502,8
3.1,79083__93502,80
2,79083__93503,16
3.1,79083__93503,85
2,79083__93504,16
3.1,79083__93504,80
2,79083__93507,8
3.1,79083__93507,90
2,79083__93511,8
3.1,79083__93511,60
2,79083__93515,16
3.1,79083__93515,100
-10.7,79085__89995,79
-10.4,79085__89996,87
-10.7,79085__89997,89
-10.6,79085__89998,83
-10.4,79085__89999,54
-10.4,79085__90000,84
-10.6,79085__90000,86
-10.7,79085__90000,98
1,79085__93502,8
2,79085__93502,8
3.1,79085__93502,85
1,79085__93515,16
2,79085__93515,16
3.1,79085__93515,100
1,79085__93525,16
2,79085__93525,16
3.1,79085__93525,80
1,79085__93526,16
2,79085__93526,16
3.1,79085__93526,80
1,79085__93531,16
2,79085__93531,8
3.1,79085__93531,80
1,79085__93536,16
2,79085__93536,16
3.1,79085__93536,90
-10.4,79092__90000,67
1,79092__93515,16
2,79092__93515,16
3.1,79092__93515,90
1,79092__93525,16
2,79092__93525,16
3.1,79092__93525,85
1,79092__93526,8
2,79092__93526,8
3.1,79092__93526,90
1,79092__93527,8
2,79092__93527,8
3.1,79092__93527,90
1,79092__93528,8
2,79092__93528,16
3.1,79092__93528,85
1,79092__93529,16
2,79092__93529,16
3.1,79092__93529,95
1,79092__93530,8
2,79092__93530,4
3.1,79092__93530,60
1,79092__93531,16
2,79092__93531,8
3.1,79092__93531,80
1,79092__93536,16
2,79092__93536,8
3.1,79092__93536,90
-10.7,79127__89997,87
-10.8,79127__89998,92
-10.7,79127__89999,83
-10.5,79127__90000,61
-10.6,79127__90000,62
-10.8,79127__90000,71
1,79127__93502,16
2,79127__93502,16
3.1,79127__93502,85
1,79127__93515,16
2,79127__93515,16
3.1,79127__93515,95
1,79127__93525,4
2,79127__93525,4
3.1,79127__93525,90
1,79127__93526,16
2,79127__93526,16
3.1,79127__93526,90
-10,79169__90000,0
1,79169__93515,16
2,79169__93515,16
3.1,79169__93515,90
1,79169__93524,8
2,79169__93524,8
3.1,79169__93524,95
1,79169__93525,16
2,79169__93525,8
3.1,79169__93525,80
1,79169__93526,8
2,79169__93526,4
3.1,79169__93526,80
1,79169__93527,8
2,79169__93527,8
3.1,79169__93527,90
1,79169__93528,16
2,79169__93528,16
3.1,79169__93528,90
1,79169__93529,8
2,79169__93529,16
3.1,79169__93529,90
1,79169__93531,16
2,79169__93531,8
3.1,79169__93531,85
1,79169__93591,4
2,79169__93591,4
3.1,79169__93591,50
-10.6,79195__89997,71
-10.6,79195__89998,82
-10.6,79195__89999,84
-10.6,79195__90000,91
1.1,79195__93502,2
1.2,79195__93502,2
1.3,79195__93502,2
1.4,79195__93502,2
1.5,79195__93502,2
1.6,79195__93502,2
2,79195__93502,8
3.1,79195__93502,90
1.1,79195__93509,2
1.2,79195__93509,2
1.3,79195__93509,2
1.4,79195__93509,2
1.5,79195__93509,2
1.6,79195__93509,2
2,79195__93509,16
3.1,79195__93509,95
1,79195__93511,0
1.1,79195__93511,2
1.2,79195__93511,2
1.3,79195__93511,2
1.4,79195__93511,2
1.5,79195__93511,2
1.6,79195__93511,2
2,79195__93511,8
3.1,79195__93511,60
1.1,79195__93515,2
1.2,79195__93515,2
1.3,79195__93515,2
1.4,79195__93515,2
1.5,79195__93515,1
1.6,79195__93515,2
2,79195__93515,8
3.1,79195__93515,70
1.1,79195__93547,2
1.2,79195__93547,1
1.3,79195__93547,2
1.4,79195__93547,1
1.5,79195__93547,2
1.6,79195__93547,1
2,79195__93547,8
3.1,79195__93547,75
1.1,79195__93589,2
1.2,79195__93589,2
1.3,79195__93589,2
1.4,79195__93589,2
1.5,79195__93589,2
1.6,79195__93589,2
2,79195__93589,8
3.1,79195__93589,80
-10.6,79225__89988,87
-10.4,79225__89989,55
-10.8,79225__89990,80
-10.4,79225__89991,57
-10.6,79225__89992,58
-10.4,79225__89993,89
-10.7,79225__89994,56
-10.6,79225__89995,53
-10.4,79225__89996,87
-10.6,79225__89997,69
-10.6,79225__89998,53
-10.4,79225__89999,68
-10.4,79225__90000,69
-10.6,79225__90000,83
-10.7,79225__90000,62
1,79225__93515,16
2,79225__93515,16
3.1,79225__93515,100
1,79225__93524,16
2,79225__93524,8
3.1,79225__93524,100
1,79225__93525,16
2,79225__93525,8
3.1,79225__93525,85
1,79225__93526,8
2,79225__93526,8
3.1,79225__93526,90
1,79225__93527,8
2,79225__93527,8
3.1,79225__93527,80
1,79225__93528,16
2,79225__93528,16
3.1,79225__93528,86
1,79225__93529,8
2,79225__93529,16
3.1,79225__93529,90
1,79225__93531,16
2,79225__93531,16
3.1,79225__93531,90
1,79225__93536,8
2,79225__93536,8
3.1,79225__93536,90
-10.7,79227__89999,78
-10.7,79227__90000,82
1.1,79227__93500,2
1.2,79227__93500,2
1.3,79227__93500,2
1.4,79227__93500,2
1.5,79227__93500,2
1.6,79227__93500,2
2,79227__93500,8
3.1,79227__93500,50
1.1,79227__93502,2
1.2,79227__93502,2
1.3,79227__93502,2
1.4,79227__93502,2
1.5,79227__93502,2
1.6,79227__93502,2
2,79227__93502,8
3.1,79227__93502,85
1.1,79227__93503,2
1.2,79227__93503,2
1.3,79227__93503,2
1.4,79227__93503,2
1.5,79227__93503,2
1.6,79227__93503,2
2,79227__93503,8
3.1,79227__93503,75
1.1,79227__93504,2
1.2,79227__93504,1
1.3,79227__93504,2
1.4,79227__93504,2
1.5,79227__93504,2
1.6,79227__93504,2
2,79227__93504,16
3.1,79227__93504,80
1.1,79227__93515,2
1.2,79227__93515,2
1.3,79227__93515,2
1.4,79227__93515,2
1.5,79227__93515,2
1.6,79227__93515,2
2,79227__93515,16
3.1,79227__93515,100
1.1,79227__93589,2
1.2,79227__93589,2
1.3,79227__93589,2
1.4,79227__93589,1
1.5,79227__93589,2
1.6,79227__93589,1
2,79227__93589,8
3.1,79227__93589,60
-10.6,79228__90000,68
1,79228__93515,16
2,79228__93515,16
3.1,79228__93515,90
1,79228__93524,16
2,79228__93524,8
3.1,79228__93524,90
1,79228__93525,16
2,79228__93525,8
3.1,79228__93525,85
1,79228__93526,16
2,79228__93526,8
3.1,79228__93526,92
1,79228__93527,8
2,79228__93527,8
3.1,79228__93527,85
1,79228__93528,16
2,79228__93528,16
3.1,79228__93528,90
1,79228__93531,16
2,79228__93531,8
3.1,79228__93531,80
-10,79283__90000,0
1.1,79283__93500,1
1.2,79283__93500,1
1.3,79283__93500,1
1.4,79283__93500,1
1.5,79283__93500,1
1.6,79283__93500,1
2,79283__93500,4
3.1,79283__93500,80
1.1,79283__93501,2
1.2,79283__93501,2
1.3,79283__93501,2
1.4,79283__93501,1
1.5,79283__93501,1
1.6,79283__93501,1
2,79283__93501,16
3.1,79283__93501,75
1.1,79283__93503,2
1.2,79283__93503,2
1.3,79283__93503,0
1.4,79283__93503,2
1.5,79283__93503,2
1.6,79283__93503,2
2,79283__93503,8
3.1,79283__93503,75
1.1,79283__93504,2
1.2,79283__93504,2
1.3,79283__93504,2
1.4,79283__93504,2
1.5,79283__93504,2
1.6,79283__93504,2
2,79283__93504,8
3.1,79283__93504,50
1,79283__93507,0
1.1,79283__93507,2
1.2,79283__93507,2
1.3,79283__93507,2
1.4,79283__93507,2
1.5,79283__93507,2
1.6,79283__93507,0
1.1,79283__93515,2
1.2,79283__93515,2
1.3,79283__93515,2
1.4,79283__93515,2
1.5,79283__93515,2
1.6,79283__93515,2
2,79283__93515,8
3.1,79283__93515,70
-10.4,79284__90000,71
-10.6,79284__90000,82
1.1,79284__93504,2
1.2,79284__93504,2
1.3,79284__93504,2
1.4,79284__93504,2
1.5,79284__93504,2
1.6,79284__93504,2
2,79284__93504,16
3.1,79284__93504,50
1.1,79284__93509,2
1.2,79284__93509,2
1.3,79284__93509,2
1.4,79284__93509,2
1.5,79284__93509,2
1.6,79284__93509,2
2,79284__93509,16
3.1,79284__93509,85
1.1,79284__93589,2
1.2,79284__93589,2
1.3,79284__93589,1
1.4,79284__93589,1
1.5,79284__93589,2
1.6,79284__93589,1
2,79284__93589,8
3.1,79284__93589,50
-10.4,79286__90000,78
-10.7,79286__90000,85
1,79286__93515,16
2,79286__93515,16
3.1,79286__93515,90
1,79286__93527,4
2,79286__93527,8
3.1,79286__93527,85
1,79286__93530,4
2,79286__93530,8
3.1,79286__93530,65
1,79286__93531,16
2,79286__93531,8
3.1,79286__93531,65
-10.6,79364__89997,64
-10.7,79364__89998,56
-10.6,79364__89999,86
-10.6,79364__90000,90
-10.7,79364__90000,86
1,79364__93526,8
2,79364__93526,8
3.1,79364__93526,95
1,79364__93527,8
2,79364__93527,4
3.1,79364__93527,80
1,79364__93530,8
2,79364__93530,8
3.1,79364__93530,65
1,79364__93531,8
2,79364__93531,8
3.1,79364__93531,80
1,79364__93536,8
2,79364__93536,8
3.1,79364__93536,80
-10.6,79365__89995,75
-10.7,79365__89996,84
-10.6,79365__89997,62
-10.8,79365__89998,85
-10.8,79365__89999,75
-10.6,79365__90000,82
1,79365__93525,4
2,79365__93525,2
3.1,79365__93525,35
1,79365__93526,8
2,79365__93526,8
3.1,79365__93526,95
1,79365__93531,8
2,79365__93531,8
3.1,79365__93531,75
1,79365__93598,8
2,79365__93598,16
3.1,79365__93598,70
-10.8,79366__89996,79
-10.6,79366__89997,79
-10.6,79366__89998,53
-10.7,79366__89999,94
-10.6,79366__90000,69
1,79366__93525,16
2,79366__93525,16
3.1,79366__93525,85
1,79366__93527,8
2,79366__93527,4
3.1,79366__93527,80
1,79366__93528,8
2,79366__93528,16
3.1,79366__93528,85
1,79366__93530,8
2,79366__93530,8
3.1,79366__93530,70
1,79366__93598,8
2,79366__93598,8
3.1,79366__93598,70
-10.7,79367__89994,100
-10.6,79367__89995,100
-10.7,79367__89996,75
-10.4,79367__89997,83
-10.6,79367__89998,82
-10.6,79367__89999,56
-10.4,79367__90000,77
-10.6,79367__90000,84
-10.7,79367__90000,77
1,79367__93502,16
2,79367__93502,8
3.1,79367__93502,90
1,79367__93524,16
2,79367__93524,8
3.1,79367__93524,90
1,79367__93530,8
2,79367__93530,8
3.1,79367__93530,65
1,79367__93536,16
2,79367__93536,8
3.1,79367__93536,90
1,79367__93598,8
2,79367__93598,16
3.1,79367__93598,70
-10.3,79368__90000,53
1,79368__93525,2
2,79368__93525,2
3.1,79368__93525,35
1,79368__93527,8
2,79368__93527,1
3.1,79368__93527,50
1,79368__93529,8
2,79368__93529,4
3.1,79368__93529,70
1,79368__93536,8
2,79368__93536,4
3.1,79368__93536,80
-10.6,79512__89997,56
-10.6,79512__89998,82
-10.5,79512__89999,68
-10.5,79512__90000,63
-10.6,79512__90000,74
1,79512__93515,16
2,79512__93515,16
3.1,79512__93515,90
1,79512__93524,16
2,79512__93524,4
3.1,79512__93524,90
1,79512__93525,8
2,79512__93525,4
3.1,79512__93525,50
1,79512__93527,2
2,79512__93527,2
3.1,79512__93527,50
1,79512__93528,8
2,79512__93528,8
3.1,79512__93528,85
1,79512__93531,8
2,79512__93531,2
3.1,79512__93531,80
1,79512__93536,8
2,79512__93536,4
3.1,79512__93536,90
-10.7,79564__89994,54
-10.4,79564__89995,77
-10.6,79564__89996,53
-10.4,79564__89997,64
-10.7,79564__89998,60
-10.4,79564__89999,76
-10.4,79564__90000,72
-10.7,79564__90000,82
1,79564__93515,16
2,79564__93515,16
3.1,79564__93515,100
1,79564__93525,16
2,79564__93525,8
3.1,79564__93525,70
1,79564__93526,8
2,79564__93526,8
3.1,79564__93526,90
1,79564__93527,16
2,79564__93527,8
3.1,79564__93527,50
1,79564__93528,8
2,79564__93528,8
3.1,79564__93528,88
1,79564__93530,8
2,79564__93530,8
3.1,79564__93530,60
1,79564__93531,16
2,79564__93531,16
3.1,79564__93531,85
1,79564__93536,8
2,79564__93536,8
3.1,79564__93536,90
-10.4,79597__89997,92
-10.6,79597__89998,85
-10.8,79597__89999,80
-10.4,79597__90000,79
-10.6,79597__90000,87
-10.8,79597__90000,89
1,79597__93515,16
2,79597__93515,16
3.1,79597__93515,100
1,79597__93524,16
2,79597__93524,4
3.1,79597__93524,90
1,79597__93525,16
2,79597__93525,8
3.1,79597__93525,75
1,79597__93530,8
2,79597__93530,8
3.1,79597__93530,60
1,79597__93531,16
2,79597__93531,16
3.1,79597__93531,85
1,79597__93532,8
2,79597__93532,8
3.1,79597__93532,75
1,79597__93536,8
2,79597__93536,8
3.1,79597__93536,90
1,79597__93599,16
2,79597__93599,16
3.1,79597__93599,80
-10.6,79643__89997,62
-10.7,79643__89998,75
-10.4,79643__89999,71
-10.6,79643__90000,76
-10.8,79643__90000,64
1,79643__93515,16
2,79643__93515,16
3.1,79643__93515,100
1,79643__93524,8
2,79643__93524,8
3.1,79643__93524,90
1,79643__93525,16
2,79643__93525,4
3.1,79643__93525,75
1,79643__93527,16
2,79643__93527,8
3.1,79643__93527,100
1,79643__93530,8
2,79643__93530,8
3.1,79643__93530,70
1,79643__93531,16
2,79643__93531,16
3.1,79643__93531,90
1,79643__93532,8
2,79643__93532,8
3.1,79643__93532,78
1,79643__93599,16
2,79643__93599,16
3.1,79643__93599,100
-10.8,79659__89996,62
-10.6,79659__89997,63
-10.4,79659__89998,74
-10.4,79659__89999,65
-10.4,79659__90000,80
-10.6,79659__90000,66
-10.8,79659__90000,83
1,79659__93501,0
1.1,79659__93501,2
1.2,79659__93501,2
1.3,79659__93501,2
1.4,79659__93501,1
1.5,79659__93501,2
1.6,79659__93501,2
1.1,79659__93504,2
1.2,79659__93504,2
1.3,79659__93504,2
1.4,79659__93504,2
1.5,79659__93504,2
1.6,79659__93504,2
2,79659__93504,8
3.1,79659__93504,70
1,79659__93509,0
1.1,79659__93509,2
1.2,79659__93509,2
1.3,79659__93509,2
1.4,79659__93509,2
1.5,79659__93509,2
1.6,79659__93509,2
2,79659__93509,8
3.1,79659__93509,80
1.1,79659__93547,1
1.2,79659__93547,2
1.3,79659__93547,1
1.4,79659__93547,1
1.5,79659__93547,1
1.6,79659__93547,0
2,79659__93547,8
3.1,79659__93547,50
1.1,79659__93589,2
1.2,79659__93589,2
1.3,79659__93589,2
1.4,79659__93589,2
1.5,79659__93589,2
1.6,79659__93589,1
2,79659__93589,8
3.1,79659__93589,50
1.1,79659__93596,1
1.2,79659__93596,1
1.3,79659__93596,1
1.4,79659__93596,1
1.5,79659__93596,1
1.6,79659__93596,1
2,79659__93596,8
3.1,79659__93596,50
-10.7,79661__89998,75
-10.6,79661__89999,82
-10.6,79661__90000,71
-10.7,79661__90000,80
1,79661__93500,4
2.1,79661__93500,50
1,79661__93501,16
2,79661__93501,0
2.1,79661__93501,80
1,79661__93511,8
2,79661__93511,0
2.1,79661__93511,65
1,79661__93515,16
2.1,79661__93515,100
1,79661__93547,8
2,79661__93547,0
2.1,79661__93547,50
1,79661__93596,8
2,79661__93596,0
2.1,79661__93596,50
-10.6,79668__89997,100
-10.6,79668__89998,98
-10.4,79668__89999,82
-10.6,79668__90000,100
1,79668__93515,16
2,79668__93515,4
3.1,79668__93515,100
1,79668__93526,8
2,79668__93526,4
3.1,79668__93526,95
1,79668__93527,16
2,79668__93527,16
3.1,79668__93527,100
1,79668__93531,16
2,79668__93531,16
3.1,79668__93531,90
1,79668__93536,8
2,79668__93536,4
3.1,79668__93536,90
-10.4,79671__89997,60
-10.6,79671__89998,83
-10.4,79671__89999,56
-10.4,79671__90000,71
-10.6,79671__90000,66
-10.7,79671__90000,85
1,79671__93515,16
2,79671__93515,16
3.1,79671__93515,100
1,79671__93525,16
2,79671__93525,8
3.1,79671__93525,75
1,79671__93526,16
2,79671__93526,8
3.1,79671__93526,95
1,79671__93527,16
2,79671__93527,16
3.1,79671__93527,100
1,79671__93532,8
2,79671__93532,8
3.1,79671__93532,80
1,79671__93660,8
2,79671__93660,4
3.1,79671__93660,50
-10,79685__90000,0
1.1,79685__93503,2
1.2,79685__93503,2
1.3,79685__93503,2
1.4,79685__93503,2
1.5,79685__93503,2
1.6,79685__93503,2
2,79685__93503,8
3.1,79685__93503,75
1,79685__93547,0
1.1,79685__93547,2
1.2,79685__93547,2
1.3,79685__93547,2
1.4,79685__93547,2
1.5,79685__93547,2
1.6,79685__93547,1
1.1,79685__93589,2
1.2,79685__93589,2
1.3,79685__93589,2
1.4,79685__93589,1
1.5,79685__93589,2
1.6,79685__93589,1
2,79685__93589,8
3.1,79685__93589,80
1.1,79685__93649,1
1.2,79685__93649,1
1.3,79685__93649,1
1.4,79685__93649,1
1.5,79685__93649,1
1.6,79685__93649,1
2,79685__93649,8
3.1,79685__93649,70
1.1,79686__93500,1
1.2,79686__93500,1
1.3,79686__93500,1
1.4,79686__93500,1
1.5,79686__93500,1
1.6,79686__93500,1
2,79686__93500,8
3.1,79686__93500,50
1.1,79686__93501,2
1.2,79686__93501,2
1.3,79686__93501,1
1.4,79686__93501,1
1.5,79686__93501,1
1.6,79686__93501,1
2,79686__93501,8
3.1,79686__93501,80
1,79686__93507,0
1.1,79686__93507,2
1.2,79686__93507,2
1.3,79686__93507,2
1.4,79686__93507,2
1.5,79686__93507,2
1.6,79686__93507,2
1.1,79686__93515,2
1.2,79686__93515,2
1.3,79686__93515,2
1.4,79686__93515,2
1.5,79686__93515,2
1.6,79686__93515,2
2,79686__93515,16
3.1,79686__93515,100
1.1,79686__93524,2
1.2,79686__93524,2
1.3,79686__93524,2
1.4,79686__93524,2
1.5,79686__93524,2
1.6,79686__93524,2
2,79686__93524,8
3.1,79686__93524,90
1,79686__93547,0
1.1,79686__93547,1
1.2,79686__93547,1
1.3,79686__93547,1
1.4,79686__93547,1
1.5,79686__93547,2
1.6,79686__93547,1
1,79686__93649,0
1.1,79686__93649,1
1.2,79686__93649,1
1.3,79686__93649,1
```

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: @Tung. Thanks for the comment. I just edited in a csv that has a 500 random sample of my data set.

Comment: Sorry, with your example, I did not  get any errors. I just run: `df %>% mutate(question = as.character(question)) %>%
  pivot_wider(., names_from = question, values_from = value) %>% 
  head()`

Comment: @dc37. hmm... I've updated my example now but I'll give your solution where u change question into a char a shot

Comment: Still no issue with your updated example. (BTW, no need to put 500 rows, you can just post the output of `dput(df[1:10,])`)

Comment: Thanks for your help @dc37. Everything's working now. I think it's either because question should be a char or in `pivot_wider` I left the first argument empty instead of having `.,`

Comment: Glad that it solves your question

Comment: wait sorry, I didn't realise, I'm just getting my original error now if I do that, where outputs contain list-cols.

Comment: Do you have other columns in your data other than what is shown? Because it doesn't give me any error on your data if I use. `pivot_wider(df, names_from = question, values_from = value)`. Also `dput(head(df, 10))` should be enough.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your help. This is really embarrassing, but I missed out on removing a single observation which was a duplicate. I'll delete the post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was because I didn't have `.` as my first argument in `pivot_wider`