# invalid type (list) for variable 'Medium' and values are not uniquely identified

Tags: r

I have been following the answer from here: [creating columns from values and placing other columns as those values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293047/creating-columns-from-values-and-placing-other-columns-as-those-values)

The code worked before, however, I made the mistake of not recording my code as I went along. Having re-traced back my steps, I came across this error:

> Warning message:
> Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.

- Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
- Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
- Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

I must have done something wrong along the way, because I avoided this error before.

I then updated the code in hopes that it would work from the answer above using the answer from here: [pivot_wider issue "Values in `values_from` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837773/pivot-wider-issue-values-in-values-from-are-not-uniquely-identified-output-w)

I also used `distinct()` as an alternative, which had no impact.

code:

```
newhabitat <- habitat_case %>% group_by(GARDEN_SIZE) %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = GARDEN_AGE:LARGE_PONDS) %>% select(-row) %>%
  mutate(GARDEN_SIZE = recode(GARDEN_SIZE, `L` = 'Large', `M` = 'Medium', 
                              `S` = 'Small', `X` = 'Missing')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = GARDEN_SIZE, values_from = value) %>% unlist()
```

The problem still arises. I must fix this because I believe its preventing me from using these covariates for the `GAM`, here:

```
gam(diversity ~ name + Medium + season, habitat_observations, family = poisson)
```

which gives this error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = diversity ~ name + Medium + Small +  :
> invalid type (list) for variable 'Medium'

Considering that both errors are related to `lists`, I will go ahead and assume that fixing the first code will fix the other.

I will go head and provide the reproducible code only for the habitat, as opposed to the combined dataframe that allows inputting the `GAM`.

Before converting the `NAs` to `X` in the `dataframe`, I tried the code above and this error appears:

```
Error: Can't combine `GARDEN_AGE` <character> and `SMALL_PONDS` <double>.
```

So it could be a problem with `SMALL_PONDS` and `LARGE_PONDS` as numeric vectors, compared with the character vectors?

Reproducible example:

```
habitat_case <- structure(list(month = c(8, 11, 10, 11, 8, 11, 3, 4, 3, 1, 10, 
12, 6, 6, 12, 10, 10, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 9, 9, 9, 4, 1, 3), 
    season = c("Summer", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Summer", 
    "Autumn", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Winter", "Autumn", 
    "Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Winter", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
    "Autumn", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
    "Spring", "Winter", "Spring"), year = c(2003, 2003, 2008, 
    2003, 2008, 2003, 2005, 2005, 2020, 2008, 2010, 2013, 2012, 
    2018, 2012, 2016, 2017, 2003, 1995, 1995, 1995, 2003, 1995, 
    1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
    1995, 1995, 1995, 2016, 2017, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 1995, 
    2007, 2007, 2008, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017), LOC_ID = c("LOC569491", 
    "LOC575706", "LOC575706", "LOC575712", "LOC575712", "LOC591752", 
    "LOC610239", "LOC614296", "LOC674315", "LOC675786", "LOC794326", 
    "LOC794326", "LOC973627", "LOC973627", "LOC1354719486425", 
    "LOC1314108", "LOC2174194", "LOC1300619774", "LOC1300613011", 
    "LOC1300612920", "LOC1300615617", "LOC1300609972", "LOC1300611058", 
    "LOC1300612277", "LOC1300605354", "LOC1300604907", "LOC1300604931", 
    "LOC1300605204", "LOC1300604590", "LOC1300604590", "LOC1300606661", 
    "LOC1300602119", "LOC1300602170", "LOC1300602081", "LOC1300622040", 
    "LOC1300622040", "LOC1300622040", "LOC1300622040", "LOC1038934429015", 
    "LOC1038934429015", "LOC287351", "LOC287518", "LOC1300624005", 
    "LOC661928", "LOC661928", "LOC661928", "LOC661928", "LOC2009340", 
    "LOC1990233", "LOC1489432713333"), GARDEN_SIZE = c("M", "S", 
    "S", "M", "S", "M", "L", "S", "M", "S", "M", "M", "L", "L", 
    "S", "M", "M", "M", "M", "S", "M", "L", "M", "L", "L", "L", 
    "L", "L", "L", "L", "M", "M", "L", "L", "S", "M", "S", "S", 
    "S", "S", "L", "M", "L", "M", "M", "M", "S", "L", "S", "S"
    ), GARDEN_AGE = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "B", "C", 
    "D", "C", "D", "C", "E", "E", "B", "B", "D", "A", "E", "B", 
    "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E", "D", "E", "E", "D", 
    "E", "C", "E", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "B", 
    "B", "B", "C", "E", "E", "E"), SMALL_DECID_TREES = c("B", 
    "B", "A", "C", "C", "C", "E", "D", "D", "B", "E", "E", "D", 
    "D", "B", "C", "D", "D", "A", "C", "C", "D", "X", "E", "E", 
    "E", "E", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "E", "D", "A", "C", "C", 
    "C", "B", "C", "E", "D", "E", "C", "C", "C", "C", "E", "C", 
    "E"), LARGE_DECID_TREES = c("X", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "X", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "D", "A", "A", 
    "C", "X", "A", "A", "C", "D", "E", "C", "E", "C", "C", "A", 
    "C", "X", "E", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "C", 
    "D", "B", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A", "A"), SMALL_CONIF_TREES = c("X", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "X", "E", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", 
    "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "E", 
    "B", "C", "E", "E", "D", "X", "E", "D", "E", "A", "D", "C", 
    "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "B", 
    "A"), LARGE_CONIF_TREES = c("X", "A", "A", "A", "A", "X", 
    "X", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "X", "A", "A", "X", "E", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "A", 
    "X", "X", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", 
    "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "B", "A"), LAWN = c("C", "C", 
    "D", "D", "B", "D", "B", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
    "D", "D", "D", "E", "B", "B", "C", "B", "D", "C", "B", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "E", "C", "B", "D", "E", "C", "C", "C", 
    "E", "E", "D", "C", "B", "E", "E", "D", "C", "B", "B", "B"
    ), FLOWERBEDS = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
    "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"), SHRUBBERIES = c("B", "A", 
    "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B"
    ), VEGETABLES = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
    "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
    "B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B"), WILD = c("A", "A", "B", "A", 
    "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
    "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "X", 
    "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "X", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), BARREN = c("A", 
    "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "C", "B", "X", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", 
    "A"), ORCHARD = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "X", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "X", "A", "X", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A"), FENCE = c("D", "B", "C", "D", 
    "C", "C", "E", "C", "D", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", 
    "E", "D", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "X", 
    "B", "B", "D", "D", "A", "B", "B", "E", "D", "E", "D", "D", 
    "X", "B", "B", "E", "D", "D", "C", "B", "B", "D"), WALL = c("B", 
    "A", "A", "X", "A", "A", "X", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
    "C", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "D", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "E", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "B", "B", "X", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "A"), BUILDINGS = c("B", "B", "C", "X", "A", "B", "X", "A", 
    "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", 
    "B", "B", "D", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "X", "B", 
    "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "X", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B"), LOW_EVERGR_HEDGE = c("A", 
    "B", "A", "X", "A", "B", "X", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
    "B", "A", "X", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "X", "B", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "B"), HIGH_EVERGR_HEDGE = c("A", "A", "A", "X", "A", "A", 
    "X", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "X", "B", "B", 
    "A", "B", "X", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
    "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A"), LOW_DECID_HEDGE = c("A", 
    "A", "B", "X", "B", "A", "X", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", 
    "C", "B", "X", "B", "A", "B", "A", "X", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "B", 
    "A"), HIGH_DECID_HEDGE = c("A", "A", "A", "X", "A", "A", 
    "E", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "X", "B", "B", 
    "A", "A", "D", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", 
    "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), OTHER_BOUNDARY = c("A", 
    "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "X", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "X", "A", "B", 
    "A", "A", "X", "A", "X", "B", "A", "A", "X", "B", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "X", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A"), HEIGHT_ABOVE_SL = c("A", "A", "X", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
    "B", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "A", "B", "X", "A", "A", 
    "X", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
    "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "X", "X", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"), BERRY_PLANTS = c("Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y"), REL_BERRY_ABUNDANCE = c("S", "M", "M", "S", "M", "M", 
    "M", "S", "X", "F", "M", "S", "S", "X", "S", "F", "M", "F", 
    "S", "S", "M", "S", "S", "M", "F", "S", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "S", "S", "M", "S", 
    "M", "S", "S", "M", "M", "S", "M", "M"), VISIBLE = c("D", 
    "D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C", "C", "B", "D", 
    "D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "C", "B", 
    "B", "C", "C", "B", "X", "C", "D", "C", "C", "D", "D", "B", 
    "C", "D", "D", "C", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "D", 
    "D"), DISTANCE_FROM_COAST = c("A", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C", 
    "D", "C", "X", "D", "C", "C", "C", "X", "B", "C", "C", "B", 
    "C", "B", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", 
    "C", "C", "B", "C", "D", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "C", "A", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), GARDEN_TYPE = c("S", 
    "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "R", "R", "X", "S", "R", "R", "S", 
    "S", "S", "S", "S", "R", "R", "R", "S", "R", "S", "S", "R", 
    "R", "R", "S", "S", "R", "S", "S", "R", "R", "R", "S", "S", 
    "R", "U", "U", "R", "S", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "S", 
    "X"), MIXED_WOODLAND = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "A", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "A", "A", "A", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "A", "X", "A", "X", "A", "A", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "A", "X", "A", "A", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "A", "X", "A", 
    "A", "A", "X", "A", "X", "X", "X"), BROADLEAVED_WOODLAND = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "B", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "B", "X", "X", "X", "X", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "X", "X", "X", "X", "B", "B", "X", "X", "X", "B", "X", 
    "X"), CONIFEROUS_WOODLAND = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "C", "C", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "C", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "C", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), SCRUBLAND = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "D", "X", "D", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "D", "X", "X", "X", "X", "D", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "D", "X", "X", "X", "X", "D", "X", "X", "X", "D", "D", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "D", "D", "D", "D", "X", "X", "D", 
    "X"), DRY_SEMI_NAT_GRASSLAND = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "E", "X", "X", "X", "X", "E", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "E", "E", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "E", 
    "X", "E", "E", "X", "X", "E", "X", "X", "X"), MARSH = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "F", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "F", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "F", "F", "F", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X"), MOOR_HEATHLAND = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "G", "G", "X", "X", "X", "X"), BOG = c("X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), PLOUGHED_FARMLAND = c("I", 
    "X", "X", "I", "I", "I", "X", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
    "I", "X", "X", "X", "I", "I", "X", "X", "I", "X", "X", "I", 
    "X", "I", "X", "I", "X", "X", "X", "X", "I", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "I", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "I", "X", 
    "X"), FARMED_GRASSLAND = c("X", "J", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "J", "X", "J", "J", "X", "J", "J", 
    "J", "X", "J", "J", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "J", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "J", "X", "X", "X"), NEAR_ORCHARD = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "K", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "K", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "K", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X"), OTHER_FARMLAND = c("X", "X", "L", "X", "X", "X", "L", 
    "L", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "L", "X", 
    "X", "X", "L", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), GARDENS = c("M", "X", 
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "X", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "X", "M", "M", "M", "X", "X", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "X", "M", "M", "M", "X", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "X"
    ), PARKS_RECREATION = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "N", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "N", "N", "N", "N", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "N", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "N", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "N", "N", "X", "N", "X", 
    "N", "X", "X", "X", "N", "N", "X"), ACTIVE_RAILWAY = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "O", 
    "O", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X"), REFUSE_TIP = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), SMALL_WATER_BODY = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Q", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Q", 
    "Q", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "Q", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Q", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "Q", "X", "X", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "X", 
    "X"), LARGE_WATER_BODY = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "R", "R", "R", "R", "X", "X", "X"), STREAM = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "S", "S", "X", "X", "X", "S", 
    "S", "X", "X", "X", "S", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "S", "S", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "S", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "S", "S", "S", "S", "X", "X", 
    "X"), RIVER = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "T", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "T", "T", 
    "T", "T", "T", "X", "X"), CANAL = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), SEASHORE = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X"), SMALL_PONDS = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "0", "X", "X", "X", "X", "2", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), MEDIUM_PONDS = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "0", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X"), LARGE_PONDS = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "0", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X")), row.names = c(NA, 50L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: perhaps you can explain from the first data frame, ```habitat_case``` .what is the final output you need? I am afraid what you are doing doesn't quite make sense. Your original data.frame has only 1 garden_size column... you cannot pivot it longer and wide again without specifying the value to pivot with

Comment: I worked it out using `as.character()` for the values that turned into lists.