# R- How to get rid of duplicate rows when using pivot_wider

Tags: r, duplicates

My data currently looks like

```
UserID Full Name  DOB     EncounterID QuestionID Name  Type  label                responses    
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          505        Intro Check Were you given any info?  yes
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          506        Care  Check By using this service..   yes
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          507        Out   Check How satisfied are you?    vsat
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          505        Intro Check Were you given any info?  no
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          506        Care  Check By using this service..   no
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          507        Out   Check How satisfied are you?    unsat
```

My code to transform it from long to wide looks like

```
gwlsubset <- read.csv("subset.csv", header = TRUE)
gwlsubset

install.packages("tidyr")
library("tidyr")

subset<- pivot_wider(gwlsubset, id_cols = c( ID, full_name, date_of_birth, encounterID,                             
                                  practice_name, practice_id  ), 
          names_from = c(label), 
          values_from = response)
```

The code works perfectly fine when I run it from a subset of my data (300 records). I get something below

```
UserID F_Name  Were you given any info?   By using this service..?   How satisfied are you?
1      John Smith  yes                        yes                        very satisfied
2      Jane Doe    no                         no                         unsatisfied
```

However when I run with 1,000+ records, I get the error below

```
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

I'm thinking that I have some duplicate rows that's prompting the error or it could be something else too.

My output also changes into random numbers.

```
UserID   F_Name   Were you given any info?   By using this service..?   How satisfied are you?
1        John Smith  1                          824                          38
2        Jane Doe    7                          176                          445
```

**How can I edit my code to get rid of duplicates? What else do you think may be causing the error and output with numbers?**

I've tried the codes in my error message but wasn't able to get anywhere for example

```
values_fn = {summary_fun}
```

Comment: This means you have more than 1 row for some combination of your ID variables. It'd be like, for example, if John Smith have two rows where the Name is "Intro". If this is expected then I think the answer showing how to make a sequence per group will help. If it is unexpected than I'd try to track down the problem by taking your dataset, grouping by all of your ID variables, and then filtering to where n() > 1. Like, simple pseudo-code, `dataset %>% group_by(variable1, variable2, etc) %>% filter(n() > 1) to print out problem rows.

Comment: Can you provide a sample using `dput` which gives an error? (`dput(gwlsubset)`) Also share what is your expected output for this data?

Comment: @aosmith yes it's expected for there to be exactly two rows but the only difference is the time they were sent out. How would you write the code to the sequence?

Comment: If you need to make unique identifiers for your different times so you keep them both (i.e., make a "time" column), then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58837832/2461552) is likely relevant.

Answer (score 0):

We may need to create a sequence column

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gwlsubset %>%
    mutate(rn = rowid(ID, full_name, date_of_birth, encounterID,                             
                                  practice_name, practice_id)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = label, values_from = response)
```

Comment: I tried that and i also tried installing the data.table and dplyr package but it didn't work. I now get the error: Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `label` doesn't exist.  but I know the column 'label' exists. This is odd.

Comment: @AshS what is the error message

Comment: @AshS your comment is broken i.e. without the error message

Comment: @AshS your input data shows the column name as `label` though?

Comment: My input does have column name as label so it's really odd that the error now says that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @AshS can you show the column names after `gwlsubset %>%
    mutate(rn = rowid(ID, full_name, date_of_birth, encounterID,                             
                                  practice_name, practice_id)) %>% names`

Comment: I get this error ```Error in mutate(., rn = rowid(mrn, full_name, date_of_birth, encounter_date,  : 
  could not find function "mutate"``` I installed the data.table and dplyr packages too.

Comment: @AsH That means you didn't load `library(dplyr)` ?

Comment: I loaded it again. It worked. Now I get the error ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `rn`.
i `rn = rowid(...)`.
x could not find function "rowid"```

Comment: @AshS you said you loaded `library(data.table)`. It is from data.table

Comment: Probably you only installed the package, but didn't load it i.e. load by `library(dplyr);library(data.table)`

Comment: it works now. I don't get that error but I do get ```Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `label` doesn't exist.```

Comment: @AshS can you show the output of `gwlsubset %>%     mutate(rn = rowid(ID, full_name, date_of_birth, encounterID,                                                                practice_name, practice_id)) %>% names`

Comment: @AshS I am suspecting that your `label` column may be having some leading/lagging spaces?

Comment: I get this ```>   "pivot_wider(names_from = label, 
+               values_from = response) %>% names"
[1] "pivot_wider(names_from = label, \n              values_from = response) %>% names"``` I don't have any spaces in the label column, I just checked. @akrun

Comment: @AshS  you are quoting the expression with `"`. I don't understand what is going on

Comment: @AshS Please copy/paste this line of code `gwlsubset %>%     mutate(rn = rowid(ID, full_name, date_of_birth, encounterID,                                                                practice_name, practice_id)) %>% names` and see what it returns

Comment: @AshS Then, I am not sure why `pivot_wider` is not able to find the `label` column

Comment: @AshS can you update your post with a small `dput` of your data that shows the issue

Comment: thanks for your time. you're awesome. I'll keep trying and changing stuff around. It didn't happen before.

Comment: @AshS try this on a fresh R session with only packages loaded `library(dplyr);library(data.table);library(tidyr)`

Comment: what else do I enter in the fresh session? I would update my post but my output still says ```UserID   F_Name   Were you given any info?   By using this service..?   How satisfied are you?
1        John Smith  1                          824                          38
2        Jane Doe    7                          176                          445 ```

Comment: @AshS you load your data `gwlsubset` i.e. `gwlsubset <- read.csv("subset.csv", header = TRUE)`

Comment: @AshS can you update your post with `dput(droplevels(head(gwlsubset, 20)))`

Comment: thanks I ran it, no error but it still shows random numbers in my output

Comment: @AshS If you can update with `dput` as in my previous comment, I can test it.  `dput` gives the exact same structure of your data and thus is reproducible

Comment: I can't copy paste it because it's sensitive information. structure It starts off with ```(list(ID = structure(c(18L, 13L, 15L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 12L, 
14L, 7L, 20L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 17L, 8L, 1L, 19L, 6L, 5L, 16L)```

Comment: @AshS the partial dput is not helpful for reproduction of data i..e if I copy/paste that on my R console, it restults in error