# Replacing NULL with NA in R after Pivot Wider

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset that I transformed using pivot_wider function. This resulted in a lot of values containing NULL. Now I want to transform those values to NA but none of my approaches seems to work:

`df %>% replace(.=="NULL", NA)`

`df[df==0] <- NA`

Also when using the pivot_wider function the values_fill = NA argument doesn't produce any NA's too.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: They see to work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have data which is something like this -

```
df <- data.frame(a1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1,2), a2 = 1:5, a3 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'))

df
#  a1 a2 a3
#1  1  1  a
#2  1  2  b
#3  1  3  c
#4  1  4  a
#5  2  5  b
```

Then you are using `pivot_wider` which returns

```
df1 <- tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = a3, values_from = a2)

#     a1   a         b         c        
#  <dbl> <list>    <list>    <list>   
#1     1 <dbl [2]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
#2     2 <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>
```

This also returns the warning messages -

> Warning message:
> Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
>
> - Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
> - Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
> - Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

To answer your question about replacing these `NULL` values with `NA` you can do -

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(across(a:c, ~replace(., lengths(.) == 0, NA)))
df1

#    a1    a         b         c        
#  <dbl> <list>    <list>    <list>   
#1     1 <dbl [2]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
#2     2 <lgl [1]> <dbl [1]> <lgl [1]>
```

But you should not ignore those warnings and check [pivot_wider issue "Values in `values_from` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837773/pivot-wider-issue-values-in-values-from-are-not-uniquely-identified-output-w) if this would be a better option for your data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace all `NULL` values in your dataframe with `NA` you can do -

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate_all( ~replace(., lengths(.)==0, NA))
```

If you want to replace all `NULL` values with `0`s, change the NA to 0 in the code.