# Need to slice dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, tidyverse, data-visualization

I have been trying to group this data frame by county however when I used pivot_wider() for the 2 casualty types, it created 2 rows for every county, I have tried fixing this but am new to R, any help would be appreciated[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2wzv.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837773/pivot-wider-issue-values-in-values-from-are-not-uniquely-identified-output-w

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.