# Is there an R function in pivot wider to spread out list-columns data from a pivoted dataset?

Tags: r, list

I'm attempting to widen a dataframe from an existing one, while keeping an extra column attached, but am receiving list-columns instead of spread out cells.

I have a large dataset I am attempting to widen:

| Location | Names | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Foo | 1 |
| A | Bar | 1.5 |
| B | Foo | 2 |
| B | Foo | 1 |
| C | Bar | 2.5 |
| D | Baz | 0.5 |

I attempted:

```
Subset <- Data %>%
  group_by(Names) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Names,
    values_from = Result,
    id_cols = Location
  )
```

And receive something like this:

| Location | Foo | Bar | Baz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.5 | etc. |
| B | c(2,1) | etc. | etc. |
| C | NA | etc. | etc. |

With this warning:
Values from `Result` are not uniquely identified; output will contain
list-cols.
• Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
• Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
• Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.

```
{data} %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Location, Names) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
    dplyr::filter(n > 1L)
```

I am wondering if there is any way to spread out the combined values in 1 cell to multiple rows to be something like this, but be able to perform this on many rows at once, as the dataframe is over 50 rows long.

| Location | Foo | Bar | Baz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.5 |  |
| B | 2 | etc. |  |
| B | 1 |  |  |
| C | NA |  |  |

Any way to do this within pivot_wider, or another function?
Thank you!

Comment: You could an identifier column to make your rows unique, e.g. try `Data %>% mutate(row_id = row_number(), .by = c(Location, Names)) |> pivot_wider(names_from = Names, values_from = Result)`. See [pivot_wider issue "Values in `values_from` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837773/pivot-wider-issue-values-in-values-from-are-not-uniquely-identified-output-w)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much! Don't know how I missed that thread you mentioned, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, one way is to add a row-id as an extra identifier, another way is to call `tidyr::unnest()` afterwards.

```
Data |>
    tidyr::pivot_wider(
        id_cols = 'location', names_from = 'names', values_from = 'result', 
        values_fn = list
    ) |> 
    tidyr::unnest(cols = -location)
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  location   foo   bar   baz
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A            1   1.5  NA  
2 B            2  NA    NA  
3 B            1  NA    NA  
4 C           NA   2.5  NA  
5 D           NA  NA     0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), Location + rowid(Names, Location)~Names)
#Using 'Result' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
   Location Names Bar Baz Foo
1:        A     1 1.5  NA   1
2:        B     1  NA  NA   2
3:        B     2  NA  NA   1
4:        C     1 2.5  NA  NA
5:        D     1  NA 0.5  NA
```